# Ubuntu 21 end up freezes when GNOME Shell Extensions are active

Tags: freeze, 21.10, gnome-shell-extension, 22.04

Ubuntu freezes when GNOME Shell Extensions is activated, the first time the problem occurred when I upgraded from `20.04` to `21.10` and the problem persisted with the latest version `22.04` installed in dual boot.

When the system freeze, I have to reboot login with `Xorg` deactivate the extensions then login again with Ubuntu.

The installed extensions:
[image]

`sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` logs :

```ps
... gnome-shell[4088]: Device '/dev/dri/card1' prefers shadow buffer
... snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration[4304]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
... snapd-desktop-i[4304]: cannot open display: 
... systemd[3802]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
... systemd[3802]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
... gnome-shell[4088]: Added device '/dev/dri/card1' (i915) using atomic mode setting.
... gnome-shell[4088]: Created gbm renderer for '/dev/dri/card0'
... gnome-shell[4088]: Created gbm renderer for '/dev/dri/card1'
... gnome-shell[4088]: Boot VGA GPU /dev/dri/card1 selected as primary
... systemd[3802]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
... systemd[3802]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
... systemd[3802]: Started Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
... snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration[4376]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
... snapd-desktop-i[4376]: cannot open display: 
... systemd[3802]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
... systemd[3802]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
... gnome-shell[4088]: Using public X11 display :0, (using :1 for managed services)
... gnome-shell[4088]: Using Wayland display name 'wayland-0'
... systemd[3802]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6.
... systemd[3802]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
... systemd[3802]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
... systemd[3802]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
... systemd[3802]: Failed to start Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- System extensions are less likely to be the culprit. These are installed using APT from the Ubuntu repositories, and thus somewhat tested for the specific distribution.
- User-installed extensions come from outside your distribution, so it is more likely the problems are there.

Disable all your user extensions, log out then back in. If the problem still occurs, also disable the system extensions. Then enable an extension and test run the system. Activate another extension, and this way you will identify the extension that causes the issue.

This assumes you are certain that it is effectively activating the extensions that causes the issue, which you indicate.

Comment: agrees with vanadium's answer, a number of extensions are still no supported in 22.04 and even if they are, they are still "glitchy". I'm using minimum extensions for now, at least till the extensions get more updates.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, the problem only happen when I activate `User-installed ` extensions not the system ones ... I guess for now I'm stuck with the top bar and window headers

Comment: Usually it can be tracked down to a single extension. Perhaps there is a conflict between Hide top bar and Pixel saver: limit to one of these. Apart from Pixel saver, you could try Unite instead.